# Get Specific Output in Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on creating a "master financial model" in excel.

The idea is that I have different building functions, which have their own specific rows in financial model.

I want to create inputs in the first sheet (already done) and have an output of the resulting financial model in the next one.

So, for example If I have Residential Function in phase 1, Hotel in phase 2 and Residential again in phase 3, then the output should include financial models for residential, then hotel and then the second residential.

The not so elegant way to do this, is just to have model for every function and then paste them into the "results" sheet. Also some editing will be required so the model knows which data to analyze. Or to have a very long sheet, which includes every possible combination and then just hide unwanted rows.

I want to automate this process, so that a person who has no clue how excel works, just needs to enter some data and have a functioning Financial model ready in no time.

Edit1: What is a Model? Financial Models are something like this: https://cdn.corporatefinanceinstitute.com/assets/financial-modeling-example-2.png

But in my model different Functions have different rows, so I need to load specific rows according to the functions I have. And load as many times, as many functions I have.

Comment: I understand nothing. What is a model? Elaborate more please.

Comment: ^^ See [ask] a question with an [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: So get results from other sheets on the summary sheet like so: "=sheet1!A1"

Comment: Are you looking for dynamic ranges? Format the input data as an excel table. Then you can reference a column, like `=SUM(Table1[Column1])`